# How to fix typescript "Property does not exist on type" with union types?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to access a property of a variable that might or might not be an object. If the variable is an object I want to read its "value" property, otherwise just read the variable.

I want to do something like this:

```
interface MyType {
    myvar: string | MyObject
}
interface MyObject {
    value: string
}

function MyComponent({myvar}: MyType){
    return(
        <div>
            {myvar.value? myvar.value : myvar}
        </div>
    )
}
```

But I get the error "Property 'value' not found on type MyObject" on `myvar.value`.

I have tried checking if the variable is an object`{typeof myvar === "object" ? myvar.value : myvar}`
, with no luck.

I have found this typescript issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28138
where they suggest using
`if("value" in myvar)` or `if(myvar.value !== undefined)`.

Unfortunately it did not work.

EDIT: is there a solution that doesn't require casting to "any"?

Comment: `myvar` is a property on some interface -> object. It's not a variable. So your code should be something along the lines of `typeof myobj.myvar === "object" ? myobj.myvar.value : myobj.myvar` or the other way around `typeof myobj.myvar === "string" ? myobj.myvar : myobj.myvar.value`

Comment: unfortunately both do not work

Comment: Can you also post your component code? I am not sure of the way you use `myvar`.

Comment: it's just a prop I get from an outer component... I updated the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a slightly better solution than casting to any.
Cast to the type that does contain the value property.

```
interface MyType {
    myvar: string | MyObject
}
interface MyObject {
    value: string
}

function MyComponent({myvar}: MyType){
    return(
        <div>
            {(myvar as MyObject).value? (myvar as MyObject).value : myvar}
        </div>
    )
}
```

as described here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Answer (score 2):

you could try something like:

```
const getValueType = (myvar: any) => {
   if (myvar typeof === "object") {
      return myvar.value
   } else {
     return myvar
   }
}

or this: 

const getValueType = (myvar: any) => {
   (myvar typeof === "object") ? myvar.value : myvar
}

render(){
  const value = getValueType(myvar)
  <div>
      {value}
  </div>
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there any other way? I'd like to not opt out of type checking

Comment: I would say no, since you're involving two different possible types. But maybe there's an "||" type conditional in Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `type` via below code

```
{typeof(myvar) === "string" ? myvar : myvar.value}
```

**OR**

You have to explicitly cast to `any`.

Can you please check the code with below line

```
{(myvar as any).value? (myvar as any).value : myvar}
```

Your code should be look like below

```
interface MyType {
    myvar: string | MyObject
}
interface MyObject {
    value: string
}

render(){
<div>
    {(myvar as any).value? (myvar as any).value : myvar}
</div>
}
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there any other way? I'd like to not opt out of type checking

Comment: I have update my answer `{typeof(myvar) === "string" ? myvar : myvar.value}`. Can you please try it?

Comment: Did you check with this code `{(myvar as any).value? (myvar as any).value : myvar}`?

Comment: that code works, but that's not really what I'm looking for

Comment: In my opinion, his solution is your solution within the confines of Typescript

Comment: can you do:
{(myvar as string | MyObject).value? (myvar as string | MyObject).value : myvar}

Comment: no, but I found out I can do  {(myvar as MyObject).value? (myvar as  MyObject).value : myvar}